# Iterating with for... in loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I have an empty array called objToArray. I'm trying to use a for-in-loop to fill the array with all of the numbers from a hash checkObj object, if the keys have a value greater than or equal to 2.

```js
const checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

const objToArray = [];

for (let values in checkObj) {
  if (Object.values(checkObj) >=2 ) {
    objToArray.push(checkObj.values())
    }
}

console.log(objToArray);
```

So far, I get objToArray as an empty array even though it should contain three elements and should equal [2, 5, 18].

Comment: Replace `Object.values(checkObj) >=2` with `checkObj[values] >= 2` and `objToArray.push(checkObj.values())` with `objToArray.push(checkObj[values])`.

Comment: This works great. So basically, checkObj[values] is equivalent to the value in the hash object?

Comment: Yes, in your `checkObj` you can access `oddNum` property value with `checkObj.oddNum` or `checkObj["oddNum"]` or  for `let key = "oddNum";` `checkObj[key]` will return same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `Object.values(checkObj).filter(x => x >= 2);`.

1. Get array of all values with `Object.values(checkObj)`.
2. Filter array and get value >= 2 with `.filter(x => x >= 2)`.

**If you want to use `for ... in` loop** then it iterates over `key` so you can get value with `obj[key]`. As you have declared `for (let values in checkObj)` `values` object will hold `key` of `checkObj`. So you can access value with `checkObj[values]`.

Check output below.

```js
const checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

// Approach 1
let result = Object.values(checkObj).filter(x => x >= 2);
console.log(result);

// Approach 2
const objToArray = [];
for (let values in checkObj) {
  if (checkObj[values] >= 2) {
    objToArray.push(checkObj[values]);
  }
}
console.log(objToArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this you wanted?

The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed, it should be key rather than values.

```js
const checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

const objToArray = [];

for (let key in checkObj) {
  if (checkObj[key] >= 2) {
    objToArray.push(checkObj[key])
  }
}

console.log(objToArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const checkObj = {
    oddNum: 1,
    evenNum: 2,
    foundNum: 5,
    randomNum: 18
};
    
const objToArray = [];

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(checkObj)) {
    // console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    if(value>=2){
        objToArray.push(value);
    }
}

console.log(objToArray);
```

Comment: As you are already iterating over `key` of `checkObj` you don't need to check `if (checkObj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {`, it will always `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

let objToArray = [];
objToArray = Object.values(checkObj).filter(elem => elem >= 2);
console.log(objToArray);
```

Comment: Besides showing a working solution to the problem, it's worth explaining what was incorrect in the OP's proposal so that they can learn from it.

Comment: @viam0Zah Thank You, surely I'll keep that practice in future

Answer (score 0):

```
const checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

const objToArray = []; 

//changing the loop into a foreach loop that iterates over the keys
Object.keys(checkObj).forEach((key => {
  if (checkObj[key]) {
    objToArray.push(checkObj[key])
  }
}))
```

Comment: ah right, that's correct, didn't think it through. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

try this: I hope you got it ..

```
let checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

let objToArray = [];

for (let values of Object.values(checkObj)) {
  console.log(values);
  if (values >=2 ) {
    objToArray.push(values)
    }
}
```